# How use the sendKeys(Keys.TAB) + sendKeys("text") for contact us form

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to fill in the few fields in a column, with commands `sendKeys(Keys.TAB)` and `sendKeys("text")`.
For Example:
We have 3 fields in Contact Us form at the bottom of the page:

- Name
- Email
- Message
  And Submit button.

I have scroll the page to the "Name" field and filled in the "Name", TAB and want to filled in the another text in the next fields (email) by using the `sendKeys(Keys.TAB)`
That's how I tried it:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#contact > div > div.main > div.form-block"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"edit-submitted-name\"]"));
webElement.sendKeys("Name");
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
webElement.sendKeys("email");
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
webElement.sendKeys("Message");
```

But it filling in all texts in the first field because webElement moving to first field ("Name").

I know, that I can use `driver.FindElement(By.xpath(## next field ##)).sendKeys("text");`
But I need exactly to use the TAB button for testing.
Maybe in Java exist the command, to type the text in the focused field? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Action class of Selenium and create a series of actions to use tab.
Also try all steps manually by clicking tab. sometime tab not work on webpages.